# Differences between matplotlib and matplotlib-base?

Tags: python, matplotlib, conda, conda-forge

While updating my packages I've noticed that there is a package named "matplotlib-base". I couldn't figure out what the difference to "matplotlib" is, neither on the official website nor here on Stack Overflow, and I also couldn't find any repository to compare the code. Any ideas?

[image: matplotlib / matplotlib-base]

Comment: difference is in the dependencies: matplotlib-base does not depend on the qt stack and is thus much lighter. It allows other packages to depend on matplotlib via matplot-base, without forcing users to also install the qt stack in their environment

Comment: I see, that's good to know, thanks @cel!

Comment: Just found the reference for that: https://conda-forge.org/docs/maintainer/knowledge_base.html#matplotlib

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The packages are similar, but differ in their dependencies: `matplotlib` depends on `matplotlib-base` and `pyqt`. Therefore installing `matplotlib` will also pull in the qt stack, while installing `matplotlib-base` does not. Users that do not need qt backends and prefer a slim installation will prefer `matplotlib-base` over `matplotlib`.

See also: https://conda-forge.org/docs/maintainer/knowledge_base.html#matplotlib